# Matlab Function Behaves Unexpectedly on Array of Inputs

Tags: matlab, function

I made a function (bisection) that calculates the zero of a function (like fzero) using the bisection method, however when I run the function I get the following warning:
"Warning: Function behaves unexpectedly on array inputs. To improve performance, properly vectorize your function to return an output with the same size and shape as the input arguments."

No idea how to solve this.

bisection function

```matlab
function[x, output, graf] = bisection(f, x0, TOL, NMAX)
graf = "no";
if(nargin > 1)
    if (~exist('TOL','var') || TOL == '~')
        TOL = eps;
    end
    if (~exist('NMAX','var') || NMAX == '~')
        NMAX = 500;
     end    
else
    error('Too few input arguments');
end
    if isa(f, 'function_handle')
        % f is a function
    else
        error('f is not a function!');
    end

    if isvector(x0)
        disp(size(x0));
        if (size(x0) > 2)
            error('x0 has too many elements!');
        else 
            if(size(x0) < 2)
                error('x0 has too few elements!');
            end
        end
        if ~isnumeric(x0(1)) || ~isnumeric(x0(2))
            error('Elements of x0 must be numeric!');
        end 
        if x0(1)>x0(2)
            error('x0(1) is > than x0(2)');
        end
    else
        error('x0 is not a vector!');
    end

    if f(x0(1))*f(x0(2)) > 0
        error('There are no zeros!');
    end

    if ~isnumeric(NMAX)
       error('NMAX must be a number'); 
    else 
        if floor(NMAX) ~= NMAX
            error('NMAX must be integer');
        end
    end

    if ~isnumeric(TOL)
       error('TOL must be numeric!');
    end 


    x0 = [x0(1), x0(2)];    
    [x, output] = do_bisection(f,x0,TOL,NMAX);

        output = [ output(1), NMAX - output(2) ];

        if("yes" == "yes")
            fplot(f,[x0(1)*2, x0(2)*2]);
            title(strcat('Grafico f = ',func2str(f)));
            xlabel('x');
            ylabel('y = f(x)');
            grid on;
            grid minor;
            set(gca,'xaxislocation','origin');
            set(gca,'yaxislocation','origin');
            hold on;
            fplot(@(x) 0,[x0(1), x0(2)],'r -');
            plot(x,f(x),'k s');
            text(x0(1), 0.5, strcat('a=',num2str(x0(1))));
            text(x0(2), 0.5, strcat('b=',num2str(x0(2))));
            text(x, -0.5, strcat('x=',num2str(x)));
            graf = "yes";
        end  
end
```

do_bisection

```matlab
function[x, output] = do_bisection(f, x0, TOL, NMAX)
    a = x0(1);
    b = x0(2);
    if f(a)*f(b)>0 
        error('non ci sono zeri');
    end
    iter = 0;
    c = (a+b)/2;
    while(iter<NMAX && (((abs(x0(2)-x0(1))/max(abs(x0(1)),abs(x0(2))))>TOL) && (abs(f(c)) > eps)))
        if(f(c)*f(a) < 0)
            b = c;
        else
            a = c;
        end
        c = (a +b)/2;
        iter = iter +1;
    end
    x = c;
    output = [ f(c), iter ];
end
```

I call the function

```matlab
f = @(x) x^2 - 5;
x0 = [1, 3];
[x, out, graf] = bisection(f,x0,10.^(-5),500);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can debug this...

The full warning looks like this:

> Warning: Function behaves unexpectedly on array inputs. To improve performance, properly vectorize your function to return an output with the same size and shape as the input arguments. 
>   
>   [...]
>     In fplot (line 161)
>     **In bisection (line 70)**

Line 70 of `bisection` is this one:

```
fplot(@(x) 0,[x0(1), x0(2)],'r -');
```

The function you're supplying is `@(x)0`, which returns a scalar `0` for a vector input (which `fplot` creates). Therefore the error makes sense, you're inputting an array to `@(x)0`, which doesn't properly handle arrays!

**Two solutions:**

1. Properly define your anonymous function to handle array inputs `x`

   ```
   fplot( @(x) zeros(size(x)), [x0(1), x0(2)], 'r-' );
   ```
2. Use a quicker function than `fplot` to simply draw a line at `y=0` between your two `x0` points.

   ```
   plot( x0(1:2), [0 0], 'r-' );
   ```

I'm suggesting `plot` because all you're trying to do is plot a straight line between two points. `fplot` is creating an array under the hood to do this for you, but it's overkill here, and `plot` is a simpler function! You could also use `line` which is even simpler but has slightly different syntax to specify styles.

Similarly, you need to change the definition of `f` to handle arrays properly by using the [element-wise power operator](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/power.html):

```
f = @(x) x.^2 - 5;
```

Comment: Very useful, thanks! One question, how do I get the full debug log?

Comment: That full stack trace should appear in your command window... if it doesn't then try running `warning( 'backtrace', 'on' );`, you may have disabled it somehow

Answer (score 1):

Your code runs fine and your bisection algorithm seems to be correctly implemented.
The warning message that appears is because of the call to [fplot](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fplot.html) function.

```
fplot(f,[x0(1)*2, x0(2)*2]);
```

This function automatically plots the function `f` defined as a function handle. It warns you, however, that your function `f` is not properly [vectorized](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html). To get rid of the warning, just change your function definition

```
f = @(x) x^2 - 5;
```

to

```
f = @(x) x.^2 - 5;
```

Notice that the `.^` indicates an element-wise exponentiation. If you simply write `x^2`, MATLAB will try to do a matrix multiplication instead.

This warning will also appear on the other `fplot` call. Change it to:

```
fplot(@(x) 0.*x,[x0(1), x0(2)],'r -');
```

And ou should be fine. This time, I just multiply the `0` for the array `x`. Essentially, the results are the same. However, multiplying `0` by `x` automatically takes into consideration the array size.

With only this changes, the function runs fine without any warnigs, and produce the desired output:

[image]